# Why calling a method on User::first() works, but User::where(...) does not?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

Works and returns true in php artisan tinker:

```
>>> User::first()->is('admin');
=> true
```

Returns error:

```
>>> User::where('id', 1)->is('admin');
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder\::is()'
```

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when using `->where()` you are building a collection, but `->first()`, returns the model.

For eloquent to return the model, you need to ask it to execute the query, by adding a `->get()`

This however also returns a collection. You can solve this by using `->first()`

```
User::where('id', 1)->first()->is('admin');
```

**Edit for comments:**

Try to do this, but the code above should work.

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
$isAdmin = $user->is('admin');
```

Comment: Now I get error : `BadMethodCallException with message 'Method is does not exist.'`

Comment: Do you have an `is` function on the user model? Make sure you copied the code exactly.

Comment: Here is how my User model looks like - https://github.com/caffeinated/shinobi/wiki/Usage

Comment: Double check that you copied the code in my example, if that doesn't work then try to use the code in the edit.

Comment: If you want to get an user by the id, you could also use `User::find($id)`. Or if you wish to get a 404 if not found `User::findOrFail($id)`.

Answer (score 1):

this **User::first()** returns **User class object**.

and **User::where('id', 1)** returns **eloquent query object**.

that is why it is not working.

however **User::where('id', 1)->get();**  will give result row array. but this also will not work to call is() on.

Answer (score 0):

In your top example you define what you want:

```
User;
```

And then you retrieve it:

```
first();
```

In your bottom example you also define what you want:

```
 User::where('id', 1);
```

However you do not retrieve it anywhere. So can't do `->is('admin')` yet, because you don't have a result to do the check on.

You can retrieve the first one that matches or a collection with everything that matches:

```
User::where('id', 1)->first(); // One result
User::where('id', 1)->get(); // Collection of results
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in other answers,where() returns a query builder, while where()->get() returns a Collection. You can then return rirst() called from the Collection.

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
$isAdmin = $user->is('admin');
```